# Toggle Photo Sets On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working on a job for a client that requires two carousel photosets that will toggle back and worth when clicked.

I have tried a number of approaches but can't quite seem to crack it.

is there a logical way to do this using the bootstrap carousel?

Comment: Please provide some code. A codepen, jsbin...

Comment: Look at : [Minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)